# finding a column name for a specific value from sql server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
-------------------------------------
|id | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 |
-------------------------------------
12  | 0902  | 0117  |'space'|'space'|
23  | 0407  | 0214  | 0518  |'space'| 
31  | 0608  |'space'|'space'|'space'|
```

How can I find out the first 'column name' having no date for  each `id`?

For an example: for `id = 31` I need the the column name `date2` in a result of a query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement (if you have `''` instead of `NULL` then you should replace `IS NULL` check with `= ''`) :

```
SELECT id
     , CASE WHEN date1 IS NULL THEN 'date1'
            WHEN date2 IS NULL THEN 'date2'
            WHEN date3 IS NULL THEN 'date3'
            WHEN date4 IS NULL THEN 'date4'
       END AS first_null_date
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that table we have 30+ different date columns. I need to pull up the first column name where ' ' starts with using where clause for specific person ID.

Comment: @user3593925 : you can grab the first non-'' _value_ with `COALESCE`, but I don't think it is possible to make something nicer for _column names_ than using `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CASE for that and also you need to use ISNULL() function if you want to consider space as NULL

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE 
         WHEN ISNULL(date1, '') = ''
             THEN 'date1'
         WHEN ISNULL(date2, '') = ''
             THEN 'date2'
         WHEN ISNULL(date3, '') = ''
             THEN 'date3'
         WHEN ISNULL(date4, '') = ''
             THEN 'date4'          
       END [COLUMN_NAME]
FROM TableName
```